# git behaviour with binary files and scalability

Tags: git, svn, version-control

In my performance tests of GIT against SVN , i found that GIT is definetly faster than SVN.
Now to see whether the performance holds good with increased size(more versions) of the projects, i forked the Perl project with 45K commits and stored it in our server. i created another repo with just the latest version.
First repo cloned in around 140 seconds and the second repo with only one commit cloned in around 19 seconds. This is a little worrying. Now with history, it loses the performance advantage it has over SVN. Is this conclusion right?

Also, i read here many posts/blogs expressing concerns over GIT performance with huge repos and with good number of binary files. Since those posts were atleast 1 yr old, do you think this is still a concern with GIT?

Yes, one way to workaround these disadvantages if it is one, is to use the shallow clone.
A shallow clone with --depth 1, takes almost the same time as clone from the repo with only 1 commit. But the shallow clone man pages talks about limitations.
    "Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of revisions. A shallow repository has a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if you are only interested in the recent history of a large project with a long history, and would want to send in fixes as patches."
Is this really a limitation or the docu is not upto-date? i had tested it with my test repos, but seems to be able to push to central repo pretty OK.

Comment: `i read here many posts/blogs expressing concerns over GIT performance with huge repos` well, i bet it can't get any bigger than the linux kernel.

Comment: How often do you `clone` a Git repository? Worrying about the time taken to do an almost once-off action seems counter-intuitive. Comparing the time taken to create a *branch* on Git and SVN, which would be a much more common action. By the way, `Git` is not an acronym; it's written as `Git` (proper noun), not `GIT`.

Comment: Just curious, how long does an initial svn checkout of a comparable-sized project take nowadays?  I haven't used it in a long time, but I remember it being a lot closer to 140 seconds than 19.

Answer (score 0):

Git behaviour with large binary files is worse. However, there is Git LFS to support for such requirements.

The difficulty occurs when you accidently push large binaries to the repository. Although you delete them later on the same branch, history remains same and repository becomes bulky. Cloning and any internal operations of git become very slow. Since it is not designed for binary files (especially large binary files).

This can be prevented from correctly setting .gitignore file initially.

Also in general even in large repositories, push/pull/status are very fast. (i.e. you don't clone always)

[Good Reading before you start](https://www.atlassian.com/git/articles/how-to-handle-big-repositories-with-git)